# How to add call logs List in android java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add call logs in List

my code working fine but it's showing only one call log,
any solution for it,
I am beginner please check my code image and help me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/joGU1.png

```
 //Recycler Function
        recyclerView_cl = view.findViewById(R.id.receyclerView_cl);
        LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        LayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView_cl.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);


        Cursor managedCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        while (managedCursor.move(3)) {
            List<CallModelClass> modelClassList = new ArrayList<>();
            CallAdapter adapter = new CallAdapter(modelClassList);
            modelClassList.add(new CallModelClass("name from", "call type", "sasa"));
            recyclerView_cl.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }
                modelClassList.add(new CallModelClass(phNumber,dir,callDate));
        }
        managedCursor.close();
```

Comment: What's your manifest  look like?

Comment: I added permission 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>

My code working fine, But I don't know how to add call logs data in modelclass for RecyclerView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these two lines out of your while loop(put theme above the loop call):

```
List<CallModelClass> modelClassList = new ArrayList<>();
CallAdapter adapter = new CallAdapter(modelClassList);
```

And also, call this: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after your `while` loop end.